# Python Generator

Tags: python

```
def countDown(i):
    if i<> 0:
        For j in countDown( i - 1 ):
            yield j
        yield i                 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for k in countDown(5):
        print k
        if k == 6 : break
```

On debugging this code , the execution path was  bit different from what I expected.
My expectation:
The "for" loop in countDown  will call the function recursively: countDown(4), countDown(3), countDown(2) , and countDown(1) and  countDown(0). At this point the if condition is  not satisfied then the "return phase" starts,   Yield j  will be executed . This will return the control back to   for loop  in "main" function.

The next iteration of this for loop , again calls countDown(5) which  starts where the last Yield left off - Yield j. This executes the for  ... countdown(i-1) loop, and calls countDown(4), countDown(3) , CountDown(2).. countDown(0). Then the "return phase" begins  and hit the first Yield j( j is now incremented from the first pass earlier). This will return the control back to the  for loop in the "main" function.

On debug, this is what I found:

1)once it fails if i<>0  as explained in at the end of recursion, it seems to execute  Yield i. Then it seems to Pop out every countDown in Stack before the control goes back to for k ... main.

2) in the Second  iteration  For k in g ,  stack  enters return phase - top to botom of the stack is  countDown(1) ,countDown(2),countDown(3), countDown(4)
then it starts "return phase". In this phase j has the value of '1'. So. how  come it does not go down to countDown(0) where i = 1  before starting the return phase?

Can anyone please explains the how this is supposed to work - combination of recursion and Generator function?  Sorry for the long windy post-  had no other way to explain it

Thx. guys  for the reply.

My understanding so far :

1) first iteration of for k in countDown(5):
entry

Function           Instruction

========           ===========
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)

countDown(2)      for j in countDown(1)

countDown(1)      for j in countDown(0)

countDown(0)       If statement fails and returns nothing

return phase

a)

countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)

countDown(2)      for j in countDown(1)

CountDown(1)      for j in countDown(0)= nothing - since countDown(0) returns nothing
                  (because of failed if condition), j has nothing annd hence yield j,
                  does not get excuted(Yield j is within the For loop). 
                  But, Yield i gets executed ,i here is 1 . So countdown(1) 
        returns 1 to the previous  recursion.

b)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)

countDown(2)      for j in countDown(1)= 1. 
                   The  value of j is now '1'. SO, the For j in countdown(1) is true . 
                 Hence, it excutes Yield j = 1. As a result countDown(2) returns 1
                  This is where j gets assigned i.

c)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)= 1
                 The  value of j is now '1'. SO, the For j in countdown(2) is true . 
                 Hence, it excutes Yield j = 1. As a result countDown(3) returns 1

...

e) Countdown(5)     for j in countDown(4) = 1
                    The value returned by count Down(4) is 1 . 
                     Hence, j is 1. So, the for j in countDown(4)
                    gets executed.

```
               The next statement Yield j  within the For statement gets exceuted.
                it returns 1.
```

for k in countDow(5) , k will get 1.This will be printed out.

2)Now to the second iteration of for k in countDown(5)

recursion "Entry"

=================

countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4) where j = 1 (Yield j was the last statement executed)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)  where j = 1

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)  where j = 1

countdown(2)     for j in countDown(1)  where j = 1

countdown(1)    executes Yield i , since the previous iteration, step a) yield was the last statement exceuted

## recursion  return

a)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4) where j = 1 (Yield j was the last statement executed)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)  where j = 1

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)  where j = 1

countdown(2)     for j in countDown(1)  where j = 1
                  Countdown(1)  returns a value of 1, j already has a value of 1,
                 so, it executes next step  which is  yield i where i = 2. 
                 countDown(2) returns yield i = 2

b)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4) where j = 1 (Yield j was the last statement executed)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)  where j = 1

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)
                 since countDown(2)  returns 2, j gets this new value j = 2
                 yield j gets executed
c)

countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4) where j = 1 (Yield j was the last statement executed)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)  where j = 1 
                  since countdown(3) returns a  value of 2 as shown in b) the new value of j is 2

...

e)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)  j becomes 2

Comment: @user848798: Please fix your indentation.  It's very hard to read this - use 4 spaces for each level of indent.

Comment: I tried posting it  and I was getting  your code  is not in the correct format. So, I was left with 2 options: ask the question and ask how it is supposed to work or  try  adding the details and  keep getting the error " your code is not formatted correct" .  Initially,  I thought the error message  is for the  the code that I put above,  I kept hitting the Curly braces{} on the toolbar   to correct the code format and got the same error message.

Comment: I took out the expectation part, and then  I was able to post  my question. I will try again to edit the question and add the descriptive part, hopefully this time I will have better luck

Comment: __Never__ use `<>` in Python, use `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will clarify the order in which the calls/yields occur:

Edit:

```
def countDown(i):
    if i<> 0:
        for j in countDown( i - 1 ):
            yield 'inner : ' + str(j)
        yield 'outer : ' + str(i)   

>>> for k in countDown(5): print k
... 
inner : inner : inner : inner : outer : 1
inner : inner : inner : outer : 2
inner : inner : outer : 3
inner : outer : 4
outer : 5
```

It pushes in all the way until i is 0, which doesn't yield anything, so neither does the for loop in countDown(1). countDown(1) next yields 1, which returns back to be yielded by countDown(2), countDown(3), countDown(4), and countDown(5). In other words, the yielded value returns to the previous caller, where it is yielded again and again until the call stack is unwound. The next generator to be exhausted is countDown(2), which yields 2 back to countDown(3), countDown(4), and countDown(5). The generators exhaust in succession until at last countDown(5) yields 5.

Comment: Yield I is within the If block , not on the same level in my code

Comment: def countdown(i):
    if i<> 0:
        for j in countdown( i - 1 ):
            yield j
        yield i

Comment: ,Sorry, I did not completely follow you here                a) "Past the for loop yields 1 from the countDown(1) call, ..... the successive for loops for i=2, i=3, i=4, and i=5" . countDown(1) on the way down executed"For  statement" to fetch countDown(0), in the return phase of countDown(1) should it not execute Yield j-which is the next statement after for loop, yield i?                               b)  "It next turns to the countDown(2) call which yields 2 to the loops for i=3, i=4, and i=5".Is countDown(2) typo? the  outer for  in main callscountDown(5)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you iterate over `countDown(5)`:

1. `countDown(5)` fetch next `countDown(4)`
2. `countDown(4)` fetch next `countDown(3)`
3. `countDown(3)` fetch next `countDown(2)`
4. `countDown(2)` fetch next `countDown(1)`
5. `countDown(1)` fetch next `countDown(0)`
6. `countDown(0)` `yield i` = 0, `countDown(0)` stop
7. `countDown(1)` `yield j` = 0
8. `countDown(2)` `yield j` = 0
9. `countDown(3)` `yield j` = 0
10. `countDown(4)` `yield j` = 0
11. `countDown(5)` `yield j` = 0
12. `countDown(5)` fetch next `countDown(4)`
13. `countDown(4)` fetch next `countDown(3)`
14. `countDown(3)` fetch next `countDown(2)`
15. `countDown(2)` fetch next `countDown(1)`
16. `countDown(1)` `yield i` = 1, `countDown(1)` stop
17. `countDown(2)` `yield j` = 1
18. `countDown(3)` `yield j` = 1
19. `countDown(4)` `yield j` = 1
20. `countDown(5)` `yield j` = 1
21. `countDown(5)` fetch next `countDown(4)`
22. `countDown(4)` fetch next `countDown(3)`
23. `countDown(3)` fetch next `countDown(2)`
24. `countDown(2)` `yield i` = 2, `countDown(2)` stop
25. `countDown(3)` `yield j` = 2
26. `countDown(4)` `yield j` = 2
27. `countDown(5)` `yield j` = 2
28. `countDown(5)` fetch next `countDown(4)`
29. `countDown(4)` fetch next `countDown(3)`
30. `countDown(3)` `yield i` = 3, `countDown(3)` stop
31. `countDown(4)` `yield j` = 3
32. `countDown(5)` `yield j` = 3
33. `countDown(5)` fetch next `countDown(4)`
34. `countDown(4)` `yield i` = 4, `countDown(4)` stop
35. `countDown(5)` `yield j` = 4
36. `countDown(5)` `yield i` = 5, `countDown(5)` stop

---

Don't know why I couldn't edit your post.

```
def countDown(i):
    if i <> 0:
        For j in countDown( i - 1 ):
            yield j
    yield i
```

It seems you just want count down, so `yield i` first. Then you will get `4 3 2 1 0` instead of `0 1 2 3 4`

```
def countDown(i):
    yield i
    if i <> 0:
        For j in countDown( i - 1 ):
            yield j
```

Comment: I am not trying to countdown. I was trying to figure out how recursion and generator fucnction works together. I just happened to give the name "countDown"

Comment: ,thx for the explanation. At 6) shouldn't it be countDown(0) . Stop? and 7) seems to execute countDown(1), yield i= 1. Also , 16,24 and 30 seems to be  where the  recursion entry stops , why does it stop at countDown(1), countDown(2), CountDown(3) instead of countDown(0) as in step 6? Also, how does the J get incremented  to 2, 3, 4, 5 in steps  25, 31 and 35

Answer (score 0):

Thx. guys  for the reply.

After further debug  :

1) first iteration - for k in countDown(5):

***recursion entry phase***

Function           Instruction

========           ===========
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)

countDown(2)      for j in countDown(1)

countDown(1)      for j in countDown(0)

countDown(0)       If statement fails and returns nothing

***recursion return phase***

a)

countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)

countDown(2)      for j in countDown(1)

CountDown(1)      for j in countDown(0)= nothing - since countDown(0) returns nothing
                  (because of failed if condition), j has nothing annd hence yield j,
                  does not get excuted(Yield j is within the For loop). 
                  But, Yield i gets executed ,i here is 1 . So countdown(1) 
        returns 1 to the previous  recursion.

b)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)

countDown(2)      for j in countDown(1)= 1. 
                   The  value of j is now '1'. SO, the For j in countdown(1) is true . 
                 Hence, it excutes Yield j = 1. As a result countDown(2) returns 1
                  This is where j gets assigned i.

c)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)= 1
                 The  value of j is now '1'. SO, the For j in countdown(2) is true . 
                 Hence, it excutes Yield j = 1. As a result countDown(3) returns 1

...

e) Countdown(5)     for j in countDown(4) = 1
                    The value returned by count Down(4) is 1 . 
                     Hence, j is 1. So, the for j in countDown(4)
                    gets executed.

```
               The next statement Yield j  within the For statement gets exceuted.
                it returns 1.
```

for k in countDow(5) , k will get 1.This will be printed out.

2)Now to the second iteration - for k in countDown(5)

***recursion entry phase***

countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4) where j = 1 (Yield j was the last statement executed)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)  where j = 1

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)  where j = 1

countdown(2)     for j in countDown(1)  where j = 1

countdown(1)    executes Yield i , since the previous iteration, step a) yield was the last statement exceuted

***recursion  return***

a)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4) where j = 1 (Yield j was the last statement executed)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)  where j = 1

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)  where j = 1

countdown(2)     for j in countDown(1)  where j = 1
                  Countdown(1)  returns a value of 1, j already has a value of 1,
                 so, it executes next step  which is  yield i where i = 2. 
                 countDown(2) returns yield i = 2

b)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4) where j = 1 (Yield j was the last statement executed)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)  where j = 1

countDown(3)     for j in countDown (2)
                 since countDown(2)  returns 2, j gets this new value j = 2
                 yield j gets executed
c)

countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4) where j = 1 (Yield j was the last statement executed)

countdown(4)      for j in countDown(3)  where j = 1 
                  since countdown(3) returns a  value of 2 as shown in b) the new value of j is 2

...

e)
countdown(5)      for j in countDown(4)  j becomes 2